# Fastify and cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, fastify

i try deployed a example in cloud functions for test and don't works, my code is:

```
`const functions = require('firebase-functions'); 
const Fastify = require('fastify') 
const fastify = Fastify() 
fastify.get("/",async (req, reply) =>{ 
reply.send({ hello: "world" }) 
}) 
fastify.listen(3000) 
module.exports = { api: functions.https.onRequest(fastify) };`
```

Someone knows how deploy the server of fastify as express

Comment: You can't listen on a port in Cloud Functions and expect it to handle requests from the internet.  That's not the way it works.

Comment: do you have documentation about this? I'm learning, in express you can assign app to the cloud function I do not know how it works on the inside so I'm asking for help, if you give me documentation explaining some things about the servers it would help me a lot, and if you have any example would be great

Comment: You're going to have to take my word for it, as I work at Google with the Cloud Functions team.  It's not feasible to document everything Cloud Functions *can't* do, so you're limited to what the documentation says you *can* do.  Listening on a high port isn't one of them.  It's not compatible with the way things work.  If you want to accept connections, you'll have to use a normal HTTP trigger, possibly hooked up to an express app.  There is plenty of existing documentation and sample code for this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: This has been mentioned here in the [fastify doc](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Server/#serverfactory)

Answer (score 2):

this issue has been explained in Fastify some days ago.

You can check the full [explanation here](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/946#issuecomment-461104668) by maintainers

I'll post here the working solution:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const http = require('http')
const Fastify = require('fastify')

let handleRequest = null

const serverFactory = (handler, opts) => {
  handleRequest = handler
  return http.createServer()
}
const fastify = Fastify({serverFactory})

fastify.get('/', (req, reply) => {
  reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  req = Object.assign({ip: ''}, {...req});
  fastify.ready((err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    handleRequest(req, res)
  })
})
```

Comment: Using typescript on cloudfunctions  I get an invalid object signature here: const fastify = Fastify({serverFactory});