# fasitify server not deploying to google cloud functions

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, fastify

I have a fasitify server with about 10 api ends. In my google functions index file I import the the fastifyFunction instance per this [documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Serverless/#implement-and-export-the-function) . and then export it as shown in `function/src/index.ts` file bellow.

```
//fastifyServer/src/index.ts

import Fastify, {FastifyReply, FastifyRequest} from "fastify";
import defaultController from "./default/defaultController";
import router from "./routers";

const f = Fastify({
  logger: true,
  ajv: {
    customOptions: {
      removeAdditional: false,
    },
  },
});

f.addContentTypeParser('application/json', {}, (_req, body, done) => {
  done(null, body);
});

/** ******Routes********/

f.register(defaultController, {prefix: "/"});
f.register(router, {prefix: "/api/v1"});

/********Run Server********/
// f.listen({port: 3000}, function(err, _address) {
//   if (err) {
//     console.error(err);
//     process.exit(1);
//   }
//   console.log("server listening on " + _address);
// });

const fastifyServer = async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
  await f.ready();
  f.server.emit("request", request, reply);
};

export default fastifyServer;
```

```
//function/src/index.ts

import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";

import {users_get_all} from "./users";
import {user_get, user_post} from "./user";

import {makeUppercase, sendWelcomeEmail} from "./triggered";

import fastifyServer from "./fastifyServer/src/index";   <------

//firebase init.
export const app = initializeApp();


// export grouped functions
exports.metrics = require("./metrics");

// export individual functions
export {
  user_post,
  user_get,
  users_get_all,
  makeUppercase,
  sendWelcomeEmail,
  // export api fastify server
  fastifyServer,       <-----
};
```

with the above code every other function deploys(user_post, user_get etc) except the fasifyServer endpoints.
In the deploy steps i dont even see firebase trying to compile or build the endpoints. Am I missing something from the docs here? Thanks.

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766349/fastify-and-cloud-functions) answer referred form [github](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/946) also check this [blog](https://mauricius.dev/how-to-use-fastify-on-google-cloud-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. thanks @sathiAiswarya.

the fastify export needed to receive the request through the gcp function http .

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

...

const fServer = async (request: any, reply: any) => {
  await f.ready();
  f.server.emit("request", request, reply);
};

exports.fastifyServer = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    fServer(req, res)
})
```